# Repeated countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, countdown

I'm trying to write a script in plain JavaScript that counts down to two specific points in time, one after the other, repeating every day. I'm not sure how to get it done.

Specifically: We have LunchTime, and then we have DinnerTime on the first day (both being Date objects).
Every day, we want the following behaviour (more or less).

[image]

At lunch-time of the first day, the "LUNCH TIME" text is in green. And there's a countdown to dinner-time of that day. And once we reach "DINNER-TIME", we get the following

[image]

And this is to repeat every day, indefinitely. 
I'm not sure how to get this done using pure JavaScript.
Currently, I have a handy piece of JavaScript as thus:

```
times = [LunchTime, DinnerTime];
var now = new Date();
var next = times.pop();
var timeRemaining = now - next.getTime();
setTimeout(styleFxn, timeRemaining);
```

The function `styleFxn` is the following:

```
    function styleFxn(){
             //Change styling on site
}
```

And I'm able to make the time switch from Lunch to Dinner on the *first* day, but never again afterwards.
*Of course*, we cannot assume that lunch-time and dinner-time every day is at the same time or that they have the same intervals between each other!

It occurred to me to use my `times` array within a loop. However, I found it annoyingly confusing to use the setTimeout within a while-loop. Specifically:

```
while((var a = times.pop())!=null){
      var now = new Date();
      var timeRem = now.getTime() - a.getTime();
      setTimeout(function(){
            //Do styling

      }, timeRem);
}
```

That didn't work.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: `while((var a = times.pop())!=null){`: No function definitions in parens. Make it `var a; while((a = times.pop())!=null){`.

Comment: When you use pop on an array, the last object will be removed from it so your loop is not an infinite loop. As you used pop once before the loop, it will execute only once for the date object that is left in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this answers your question or not but I think, your problem can be solved by simply recursing through your styleFxn. See the following code along with the comments:

```
times = [LunchTime, DinnerTime];
var now = new Date();
//YOU HAVE USED POP METHOD BUT HAVE NOT SPECIFIED HOW THE NEXT LUNCH OR DINNER
// TIME WILL BE ADDED TO YOUR TIMES ARRAY SO
// I WILL ASSUME YOU HAVE SOME METHOD FOR THAT
var next = times.pop();
var timeRemaining = now - next.getTime();
setTimeout(styleFxn, timeRemaining);

function styleFxn(){
    //Change styling on site
    //THIS ASSUMES THAT YOU HAVE APPROPRIATE
    // STYLING LOGIC FOR RECURSION AS WELL
    // AS ANOTHER METHOD TO ADD NEW LUNCH AND
    // DINNER TIME TO YOUR times ARRAY

   //CALL FUNCTION/METHOD TO UPDATE times ARRAY
    now = new Date();
    next = times.pop();
    timeRemaining = now - next.getTime();
    //**********************************
    setTimeOut(styFxn,timeRemaining);
    //*********************************
    // NOW THE PROCESS WILL REPEAT INDEFINITELY

}
```

Comment: How would I stop the infinite loop. My method for "loading" all of the data into times is in the `init()` function from which the first `setTimeout(styleFxn, timeRemaining);` is called. How would I have to modify my code to somehow "pause" the infinite looping to go and reload my times?

Comment: @arkate: Basically, you can call the method you want to use to update your times array before you reach to the last line of code as I mentioned in above code comments. I think that should work but if you can post your init method, we can guide you little more if the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the really quick answer..I think I can take it from here. Accepted :)

Comment: glad I can help! enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Queue is more suitable for this task as you will need to get the date objects in the order that you put them the data structure.

You need to define a function that starts a timeout and after the timeout calls itself again. If you use a while loop you will face performance degradation in the browser.

Every time you get a date object from the queue, you need to push it back so that you always have a date to work with. But don't forget to increase date by one day before putting it back.

The following code will let you change between the dinner and lunch texts. You can change it for your need to create a countdown.

I hope it helps...

```
// Initialise your date objects
var lunchTime = new Date();
lunchTime.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
var dinnerTime = new Date();
dinnerTime.setHours(18, 0, 0, 0);

// Shift the date value by one day if required
var currentTime = new Date();
if (currentTime > dinnerTime) {     // Both Lunch & Dinner time has passed 
    dinnerTime.setDate(dinnerTime.getDate() + 1);
    lunchTime.setDate(lunchTime.getDate() + 1);
} else if (currentTime > lunchTime) {   // Lunch time has passed
    lunchTime.setDate(lunchTime.getDate() + 1);
}

// push those date objects to a queue
var times = [];
times.push(lunchTime);
times.push(dinnerTime);         

function setCountdown(timesArray) {
    var a = timesArray.shift();
    var now = new Date();
    var nextTime = a.getTime();
    var timeRemaining = nextTime - now.getTime();

    setTimeout(function() {
        var hour = a.getHours();
        if (dinnerTime.getHours() == hour) { // DinnerTime
            // CSS to show DinnerTime text
        } else {
            // CSS to show LunchTime text
        } 

        // After time comes push the time back again but increase its day by one
        timesArray.push(new Date(a.setDate(a.getDate() + 1)));

        // Call the same function to initialise a timeout again     
        setCountdown(timesArray);

    }, timeRemaining);
};

setCountdown(times);
```

Comment: The issue here is that as mentioned in the question "we cannot assume that lunch-time and dinner-time every day is at the same time or that they have the same intervals between each other". Each and every time we're going to have to go back to the function and get it 're-loaded'. Since the first answer was more suitable to my request, I accepted that--I wouldn't have to change my code so much. But I really like the elegance of your solution and I hope it helps someone else :)